# Can't `su` to another user with login shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, su

I'm working on the Linux From Scratch project, and I've got a very basic problem I can't figure out.

I'm told to use `su - lfs` to change to my "lfs" user. If my understanding is right, the center dash means I should switch users *and* run that user's login items, namely `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

But when I try (on Manjaro), I get this:

```
$ su - lfs
Password:
Job 1, 'su - lfs' has stopped
$
```

I've checked all the obvious things I've read: `lfs` has a password, a shell (in `/etc/passwd`), and a home directory.

I can do the simpler `su lfs` and change users, but it doesn't process those login files and I end up with some incorrect environment variables.

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
`.bashrc`...

```
set +h
umask 022
LFS=/mnt/lfs
LC_ALL=POSIX
LFS_TGT=$(uname -m)-lfs-linux-gnu
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
export LFS LC_ALL LFS_TGT PATH
export MAKEFLAGS='-j 6'
export EDITOR='nano'
```

... and also `.bash_profile`...

```
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
```

... and the relevant entry from `/etc/passwd/`...

`lfs:x:1001:1001:lfs:/home/lfs:/bin/bash`

Comment: Could be an issue with the content of those files... can you post them?

Comment: @ivanivan - added to main question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why I didn't try this earlier, but after I get `Job 1, 'su - lfs' has stopped`

All I need to do is bring it to the foreground with `fg`.

I don't exactly understand the "why" part of this, but it works... problem solved.

Comment: I had the same issue and your answer helped me. I had just read the docs from LFS but this didn't click until I saw your answer: 

`In some host systems, the following command does not complete properly and suspends the login to the lfs user to the background. If the prompt "lfs:~$" does not appear immediately, entering the fg command will fix the issue.`
From [4.3. Adding the LFS User](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/addinguser.html)